# How to parse JSON in Android Iam using Volley library?

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

```json
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Bombay, Maharashtra, Inde" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "New Delhi, New Delhi 110001, Inde" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 457 km",
                  "value" : 1457222
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "22 heures 8 minutes",
                  "value" : 79663
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: You wrote just code. Without any explanation of what you'd want to do, how can I even try to help you out?

Comment: Parse to ListView? Have a look at this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for reference.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("jsonResponse");
    JSONArray jsonArr= jsonObj.getJSONArray("destination_addresses");
    String[] arrDestinations=new String[jsonArr.lLength()];
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++)
        arrDestinations[i]=jsonArr.get(i);

    jsonArr= jsonObj.getJSONArray("origin_addresses");
    String[] arrOrigins=new String[jsonArr.lLength()];
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArr.length();i++)
        arrOrigins[i]=jsonArr.get(i);

    JSONArray rows = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");
    for(int i =0; i < rows.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject rowObj = rows.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray rowElements = rowObj.getJSONArray("elements");
        for(int element = 0; element < rowElements.length(); element++) {
               // get the elements and parse
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for responding i have traced the json doc  :)

Comment: If this did help you then please upvote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Logcat` to see extracted values from `JsonObject`.

```
       try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JsonObject.toString());

            JSONArray destination_addresses = jsonObj.getJSONArray("destination_addresses");
            for (int i = 0; i < destination_addresses.length(); i++) {
                Log.e("Values", "destination_addresses = " + destination_addresses.get(i));
            }

            JSONArray origin_addresses = jsonObj.getJSONArray("origin_addresses");
            for (int i = 0; i < origin_addresses.length(); i++) {
                Log.e("Values", "origin_addresses = " + origin_addresses.get(i));
            }

            JSONArray rows = jsonObj.getJSONArray("rows");
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject rowObject = rows.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray rowElements = rowObject.getJSONArray("elements");
                for (int j = 0; j < rowElements.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject elementObject = rowElements.getJSONObject(j);
                    JSONObject distanceObject = elementObject.getJSONObject("distance");
                    String distanceText = distanceObject.getString("text");
                    String distanceValue = distanceObject.getString("value");

                    JSONObject durationObject = elementObject.getJSONObject("duration");
                    String durationText = distanceObject.getString("text");
                    String durationValue = distanceObject.getString("value");
                    Log.e("Values", "distanceText = " + distanceText + "\ndistanceValue = " + distanceValue + "\ndurationText = " + durationText + "\ndurationValue = " + durationValue);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: thank you for responding i have traced the json doc  :)

Comment: Ur Welcome :) @HarshaVardhan

Comment: first thing i have convert it in json Hirarchy tree then i ve understand to parse      :)  this tool really helps   http://basic4ppc.com:51042/json/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for parsing and generating JSON in Android:
http://github.com/amirdew/JSON